# run a task in a task and evaluate its result in sbt

Tags: scala, task, sbt

I am interested to write a task that creats a starter of my project that doesn't involve sbt at all anymore. Thankfully sbt knows all information, so that I can create my own starter. In the Interactive mode those four commands show me all information I need to create my starter, but they just print them out, and I am unable to process them further

```
show java-options
show unmanaged-jars
show managed-classpath
```

I would like to process the result of those three tasks further, but right know I don't know how to do it. The task defenition in the wiki is very confusing and the <<= operator even more.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much to creating a task. I assume you looked at the [wiki](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Tasks) about it, and did not understand something. I think you'd do something like this example:

```
val stringTask = TaskKey[String]("string-task")
stringTask <<= (sampleTask, intTask) map { (sample: Int, intValue: Int) =>
    "Sample: " + sample + ", int: " + intValue
}
```

The `<<=` method simply says that the definition of `stringTask` depends on other tasks.

On the other hand, maybe you need a Runner, not a Task.

Writing a runner is, unfortunately, not quite that simple. I have on in [this project](https://github.com/dcsobral/scala-foreach-benchmark). Here's its definition:

```
class MyRunner(subproject: String, config: ForkScalaRun) extends sbt.ScalaRun {
  def run(mainClass: String, classpath: Seq[File], options: Seq[String], log: Logger): Option[String] = {
    log.info("Running " + subproject + " " + mainClass + " " + options.mkString(" "))

    val javaOptions = classpathOption(classpath) ::: mainClass :: options.toList
    val strategy = config.outputStrategy getOrElse LoggedOutput(log)
    val process =  Fork.java.fork(config.javaHome,
                                  config.runJVMOptions ++ javaOptions,
                                  config.workingDirectory,
                                  Map.empty,
                                  config.connectInput,
                                  strategy)
    def cancel() = {
      log.warn("Run canceled.")
      process.destroy()
      1
    }
    val exitCode = try process.exitValue() catch { case e: InterruptedException => cancel() }
    processExitCode(exitCode, "runner")
  }
  private def classpathOption(classpath: Seq[File]) = "-classpath" :: Path.makeString(classpath) :: Nil
  private def processExitCode(exitCode: Int, label: String) = {
    if(exitCode == 0) None
    else Some("Nonzero exit code returned from " + label + ": " + exitCode)
  }
}
```

And it gets used like this:

```
runner in Compile in run <<= (thisProject, taskTemporaryDirectory, scalaInstance, baseDirectory, javaOptions, outputStrategy, javaHome, connectInput) map {
  (tp, tmp, si, base, options, strategy, javaHomeDir, connectIn) =>
    new MyRunner(tp.id, ForkOptions(scalaJars = si.jars, javaHome = javaHomeDir, connectInput = connectIn, outputStrategy = strategy,
      runJVMOptions = options, workingDirectory = Some(base)) )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer so quickly, but you might tell me what all those differences between Runners Tasks etc is? Right at the moment I am done with sbt and hate it, I just do copy paste and string parsing, I am by far faster doing that than writing this sbt crap.

Comment: @Arne A `Runner` has specific methods that SBT can use to do things like interrupt the running process. That specific runner executes the code by forking a `java` process, and otherwise acts pretty much like the default runner (ie, will be affected by the stuff that affects the default runner). Re-reading your question, however, maybe this isn't what you want... do you want to create a _script_ that will run your process? I think I saw that not so long ago on the mailing list.